# Get files from SFTP server and manipulate in memory

Tags: bash, shell-script, sftp

Is there a **BASH** way that is able to access a SFTP server, "access" a file and without downloading it read it in a *buffer*, manipulate the content and then store it locally.

I know this can be done using a perl script.

`@file=$sftp->get($file);`

I am looking for a similar approach in bash.

The intend is to get away from Perl script and implement the functionality in bash.

Thanks

Comment: Net::SFTP's $sftp->get($file) downloads the entire file. Were you looking for something that reads and writes chunks of the file?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick. Yes it download the file but it is assigned to a variable not to a psychical file. There is a good attempt below using curl, but unfortunately it is not a SSH server. It is a true sftp server with no login account.

Comment: Why is in-memory the requirement? Can you save the file to a `tmpfs` mount and manipulate it from there?

Comment: @PackedUp sftp is implemented via SSH. Not sure you're going to be able to get around using the tunneling protocol required for sftp to work.

Comment: @Bratchley. I cannot download the file anywhere even for temporary needs because of the data sensitivity.

Comment: @PackedUp most requirements like that are because permanent storage is nonvolatile and they're worried that if you interrupt the process (e.g shut down the system halfway through) it'll be sitting there vulnerable, available for analysis. If you shut down a system halfway through saving to `tmpfs` the file is just gone.

Comment: Would SSHFS using sftp https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshfs be a possibility? It's a virtual filesystem.

Comment: Maybe your `vim` can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450525/vim-support-to-upload-via-sftp

Answer (score 2):

With [libcurl with sftp](https://askubuntu.com/a/195547/336375) support:

```
 curl sftp://sftp.example.com -o - | do_some_magic > filename
```

---

I have tested curl on these Linux distributions/Unix:

libcurl with built-in sftp support: RHEL6, RHEL7

Without: RHEL5, Ubuntu 11.04, Ubuntu 14.04, Solaris 11

Comment: curl: (1) Unsupported protocol: sftp

Comment: @PackedUp What version and from what distribution? Or, build yourself, and make sure to link against libssh2.

Comment: @mattdm CentOS. Sorry I am not looking at a rebuild solution. Thanks.

Comment: @PackedUp What CentOS version? Just checked RHEL7 and Scientific Linux 6.5 (what I happened to have at hand) and both support it.

Comment: @mattdm CentOS 6. I checked on my RHEL system (5.10). The issue persists. Thanks

Comment: I just verified that it works on RHEL6 as well. It should be working on your CentOS 6 system then.

Comment: Possibly it wasn't in RHEL 6.0 and released in an update? I can check, but the right answer here is probably _you should update your system_ in any case. :)

Comment: @mattdm  I was able to verbose the curl log  ` About to connect() to 11.11.11.12 port 990
*   Trying 11.11.11.12... No route to host
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host` .. But I am successful in connecting using the sftp command.

Comment: @PackedUp if you're dealing with high side stuff, shouldn't you redact those IP addresses? Especially if this post is used as a way to determine the inner workings of some process you guys use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a remote file without downloading it, but you can download a remote file without saving it to the local filesystem. Not with bash itself, which doesn't include support for SFTP, but with command line utilities.

The `sftp` client from OpenSSH doesn't seem to be able to do that: it insists to get a seekable output location, which excludes piping it out into a command substitution.

[Curl can download a file to standard output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178196), but it is not always built with SFTP support (it started out as an HTTP downloader).

Since you already know how to do it in Perl, you could just run Perl.

Alternatively, mount the remote filesystem over [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), and then access it with any command such as `cat`.

```
mkdir foo
sshfs example.com:/path/to/directory foo
content=$(cat foo/somefile)
fusermount -u foo
rmdir foo
```

Alternatively, do things the “normal” shell way. Shells aren't designed to do fancy data manipulations in memory, they're mostly good at executing other commands and working with files. Working with file contents typically involves pipelines and, sometimes, temporary files.

```
my_tmp_dir=
trap 'rm -rf "$my_tmp_dir"' EXIT INT HUP
my_tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d)
echo 'get remotefile localfile' | { cd "$my_tmp_dir" && sftp -q; }
content=$(cat "$my_tmp_dir/localfile")
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write up. It makes sense and completes my understanding. I didn't want to go through the perl route because of external perl SFTP module dependencies. I agree with you about "Shells aren't designed to do fancy data manipulations in memory". I ended up writing the script in ruby, which again has a gem dependency. I am going try the remote mount and check it out.