# cat a remote file from sftp

Tags: sftp

I'm in an SFTP session and navigated to a deep directory. I did `ls -l`, saw a small file, and want to just read it. I would prefer to do it while I'm still in SFTP, rather than starting up a new terminal, doing SSH, navigating to that deep directory, and then reading it, then going back to SFTP to continue.

Is there a way to do that?

SFTP has no `cat` command.

I tried `get file -`, hoping it would treat `-` as stdout, but that just creates a file called "-".

I tried `get file /dev/stdout`, but that results in:

```
sftp> get file /dev/stdout
Fetching /home/username/file to /dev/stdout
/home/username/file                100%  506     9.0KB/s   00:00
ftruncate "/dev/stdout": Invalid argument
Couldn't write to "/dev/stdout": Illegal seek
```

Another way might be `get file /tmp/file`, come out of SFTP, read /tmp/file, delete /tmp/file, and get back into SFTP, but that's equally as tedious. Is there an easy way?

Comment: lftp can do this easily. It's a matter of client's features.

Comment: perhaps [sshfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202919/117549) would help? (search for sshfs here, or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178255/117549)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having cat in sftp would mean that the contents of the file will still have to travel through the network, to your local machine, to be displayed for your eyes, which is basically, you get ther file. You don't have to "come out of SFTP", as sftp has `!command`.

So, you can do:

```
sftp> get file
sftp> !cat file
```

Comment: Useful to know.  I guess you might also want do `lcd /tmp/` or similar before downloading, so the file goes into your own /tmp folder rather than littering whatever directory you ran sftp from.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute cat via sftp because it is designed specifically for file transfer. You can check "man sftp" to find the list of commands that you can use while in the interactive shell.